# Unable to access the class variable through the exception object

Tags: php, class, object, exception, amazon-web-services

Following is a `var_dump` of an exception object:

```
object(Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception)[98]
  private 'response' (Aws\Exception\AwsException) => 
    object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)[90]
      private 'reasonPhrase' => string 'Conflict' (length=8)
      private 'statusCode' => int 409
      private 'headers' => 
        array (size=6)
          'x-amz-request-id' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'x-amz-id-2' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'content-type' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'transfer-encoding' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'date' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'server' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      private 'headerLines' => 
        array (size=6)
          'x-amz-request-id' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'x-amz-id-2' => 
            array (size=1)

          ....
          ....
```

The type of the variable is `object`, so when I try to access the `response` variable as :

```
catch(Exception $exc) {
        var_dump($exc);
        echo($exc->response); // Access response variable
}
```

I get :

```
 Undefined property: Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception::$response
```

Why am I unable to access the class variable?

Comment: coz its private property, can you paste all dump ?? via print_r ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a `private` variable directly. However, you could use a public `get` method here.

`$exc` is a **`Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception`** class object which is a subclass of **`Aws\Exception\AwsException`**.

By your code:

```
catch(Exception $exc) {
    var_dump($exc);
    echo($exc->getResponse()); //Get the received HTTP response if any
}
```

A better way would be :

```
catch (AwsException $e) {
    // This catches the more generic AwsException. You can grab information
    // from the exception using methods of the exception object.
    echo($exc->getResponse());
    echo($exc->getStatusCode());
}
```

[Reference Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Exception.AwsException.html)